# Placing a JButton on a specific Co-ordinate [Need Help]

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I want to put a Jbutton on a particular coordinate in a JFrame. I have tried using setLocation and setBounds but neither of them work. I think I am doing something wrong for sure. I'm new to Java and have tried searhcing this up

My Output:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class BingoHelper extends JFrame implements WindowListener, ActionListener{
    JTextField text = new JTextField(10);

    private JButton b; {
            b = new JButton("Click to enter name");
            }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        String fn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Username:");
        String sn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Password:");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome " + fn + " " + sn + ".", "", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        text.setText(fn + " " + sn);
        b.setVisible(false);
        text.setVisible(true);
        text.setBounds(100,20,49,90);
        b.setBounds(100,90,22,30);
    } 

    public BingoHelper(){
        super("BINGO");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(b);
        add(text);
        text.setVisible(false);
        b.setVisible(true);
        b.setBounds(0,0,220,30);
        b.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        dispose();
        System.exit(0);

    }
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object responsible for the location of the components is a [Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html). However if you want to specify the coordinates yourself you'll have to specify a [null layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html) in the `Container` where you put the component.

In your code you set the layout of the frame's content pane (a `Container`) to `FlowLayout`, but you need to set it to null: `setLayout(null);`. Then you can use setBounds on the JButton to specify its location.

However it is **strongly** recommended to use a Layout Manager (probably several of them using `JPanel`s).

**Edit**: To give you a glimpse of why there are so many different layouts check out [the visual guide to layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Answer (score 2):

Most of of the time, there's no reason to position UI elements via coordinates. You should really check out Layout Managers. You're opening up a can of worms that I don't think you'd like to deal with. For example, you can run into complications when the user tries to re-size the screen.

Check this documentation out instead: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

**GridBagLayout** is really clunky and a pain to use, but it should be flexible enough to accommodate just about anything you're trying to accomplish. However, you should look into the other layout managers as well. You may be able to use one or more of them in conjunction to accomplish the look and feel you're going for.

That being said, I hate Java's built-in layout managers. Once you get a feel for how they work, you should definitely move onto a third party layout system. [MIGLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) is pretty boss.